# No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier ‘org.cocoapods.BigNumber’ is correct

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

App Store Connect wont let me upload my app. Seemingly no matter what I do, I get this error when uploading via Xcode directly to App Store Connect:

"No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier ‘org.cocoapods.BigNumber’ is correct."

I know that this is a well known error, but still, others solutions didn't help me. The bundle ID (com.xxx.xxx) is exactly the same as in Xcode and I've updated all the pods with terminal. Currently I am filling out all the information about the App on App Store Connect, some said that would help. If so, I will let you know. If anybody has other ideas, please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those wondering: I did the thing where I had to set the product type/code or so (sorry, no access to Xcode right now) to 'APPL' (without the ''). All the time, I had it at 'AAPL' and was wondering why it didn't work. That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to log into https://itunesconnect.apple.com/ and create a new app before you can upload your binaries via xcode.

-> Copied from a github forum, but yes that's what I had to to in order to make it work :)

Comment: If this is taken from an external source, please link the source.

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing the steps, you have signed/built the app and are stuck on the last step to upload to App Store connect, just make sure you have:

1. Registered a Bundle Id/Provisioning Profile on [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com).

   Then go on and build your app.
2. Create an App on iTunes Connect(AppStore Connect) (Internally [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) redirects to [AppStore Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com)).

Then come back to XCODE, archive the app from `Top Menu > Product > Archive` and follow the rest of the steps as the same.

Refer to this [medium article](https://medium.com/@iqan/releasing-flutter-ios-app-to-testflight-using-xcode-21571299dbc3) for the exact steps. This contains the latest steps with screenshots. These are the steps for uploading a flutter app to testflight but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

In my case rebooting my system did the trick.